# Calling a client's remote method in Twisted perspective broker

Tags: python, twisted, perspective-broker

I am using twisted's Perspective Broker to talk between the client and the server. The client requests from the server a remote method 'remote_ftp_listen'. This causes the PB server to initiate a FTP connection and wait till a file matching some pattern is found in a directory, then the PB server must inform the client of that event (found a file in the desired ftp directory).

How to achieve this reverse call (PB Server > PB client) ? something like telling the server that it has to callback a method on the client side ... if it's not possible through PB, then what would you advise to do to realize it ?

Answer (score 2):

When the client does this:

```
clientDeferred = server.callRemote("ftp_listen", arguments)
```

And the server does this:

```
def remote_ftp_listen(self, arguments):
   # ... some stuff with FTP ...
   serverDeferred = ftpConnection.findSomeFile(arguments)
   return serverDeferred
```

where `findSomeFile` returns an instance of `Deferred`, then the PB server will send back a response to the client after `serverDeferred` fires, and `clientDeferred` will fire after the client receives that response from the server.

You can also return multiple results this way, if you're happy for them to all be returned at once (which will happen when the last one is found).  Just adjust the server:

```
from twisted.internet.defer import gatherResults

def remote_ftp_listen(self, arguments):
   # ... some stuff with FTP ...
   serverDeferred = gatherResults([ftpConnection.findSomeFile(a) for a in arguments])
   return serverDeferred
```

The `Deferred` returned by `gatherResults` will fire with a list holding the results of all of the `Deferred` objects in the list passed to it.

If you need to send results to the client as soon as they are discovered, rather than bundling them all up into a single result list, then you need to do something different.  Have the client pass a `Referenceable` to the server and have the server call remote methods on that object.  You can read more about this approach on the Twisted website in the PB documentation.  http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/pb-usage.html in particular goes into this topic.  The document focuses on passing `Referenceable` objects from server to client, but the reverse works exactly the same way.  So if you have a `Referenceable` on your client that you pass to the `ftp_listen` remote method on the server, then the server will be able to turn around and use `callRemote` to call methods on the client object.

Comment: In fact, i need to ask my server to callback on the client whenever it finds a file.
The deferred can only be fired once, but i need it to be called as many times as files are found.

I'm having a jelly exception when i try to pass a callback like this: server.callRemote("ftp_listen", arguments, fileFoundCallback)

Comment: Your question says "a file" rather than "an arbitrary number of files"  :/  I'll try to update the answer to handle multiple files, though.